# Panel time-series, using R

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data

The data:
I have a balanced panel of 500 – 800 observations (municipalities in Lower-Saxony, Germany) and 26 time periods (1988 – 2014). My dependent variable can only obtain values greater than zero (count data).

The problem:
At first I thought that I can use a fixed-effects panel model, but with a bit of self-study I’ve found that a dataset with both large N and large T (panel time-series) cannot be applied with a normal fixed- or random-effects panel model, because of heterogeneity, dynamics, cross-sectional dependence…
Unfortunately, I am not very experienced with time-series statistics and don’t know how this fact restricts the applicability of the plm-function (or pglm-function) in the plm-package (pglm-package) in R.

The question:
So,  is there any package in R which contains a function for panel data with both large N and large T? How can I specify my model to use the plm-function? 
Or is there any other solution for my problem?

I really appreciate your help!